# Is there a basis for sequences?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, continuity, nets

There are various equivalent definitions of a topological space and for some of them we have the concept of basis: a basis of opens sets, or a basis of neighbourhood.

This concept simplifies verifying continuity to a great degree.

So being in the most simple case possible: given a sequence space, what is a subset of sequences over which checking the continuity is sufficient?

For the general statement.
Given a topological space $(X,\mathrm{Nets}_X)$ where $\mathrm{Nets}_X$ are all the converging nets of $X$, what is a subclass of $\mathrm{Nets}_X$ over which we can check continuity?

Comment: Possibly an equivalence modulo finite initial segments (since only tails of sequences matter), but this won't be a subset of sequences.

Comment: For nets with values in $X$ we can always reduce continuity by checking nets with index set in the "universe of $X$" (define $X_0 = X$, $X_{n+1}= X_n \cup \mathcal{P}(X_n)$ for all $n \ge 0$ and the universe of $X$ is then $\bigcup_n X_n$. This allows one to take a *set* of nets instead of proper classes. I read about this in a recent preprint.